# Actionscript 3 - Android App not updating content. Holding old in memory?

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I've written the following code (AS3) that loads an XLM file, gets the day of the week and then displays, on stage, a corresponding question.

It works great on my computer when I test in Flash. But on my Galaxy S2, it only displays the question-of-the-day, for the day it was installed and doesn't update each day with a new question.

What am I missing here? 
Thanks in advance.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<questions7>
    <question day="0"><![CDATA[Question for Sunday ]]></question>
    <question day="1"><![CDATA[Question for Monday ]]></question>
    <question day="2"><![CDATA[Question for Tuesday ]]></question>
    <question day="3"><![CDATA[Question for Wednesday ]]></question>
    <question day="4"><![CDATA[Question for Thursday ]]></question>
    <question day="5"><![CDATA[Question for Friday ]]></question>
    <question day="6"><![CDATA[Question for Saturday ]]></question>
</questions7>
```

And the Actionscript:

```
//Loads external XML file
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("questions7.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

// Get day number of the week
var myDateDay:Date = new Date();
var dayNumber:int = myDateDay.day;

//To display question of the day
function processXML(e:Event):void {
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    var question:XMLList = myXML.question.(@day == dayNumber);
        trace(question);

    var myText1:TextField = new TextField();
        myText1.text = question;
        myText1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
        myText1.border = false;
        myText1.width = stage.stageWidth - 100;
        myText1.multiline = true;
        myText1.wordWrap = true;
        myText1.y = 200;
        myText1.x = 50; 

    // Add to stage
    addChild(myText1);
}
```

Comment: I just went and did a Force Stop, in my phone, restarted the App and it loaded the correct question of the day. So, is the app holding the memory of a date? How would I clear that when the App is closed?

Answer (score 0):

you could listen for the deactivate event, and close your application that way your app will start with fresh data

```
    stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivate);


    private function deactivate(e:Event):void 
    {
        // auto-close
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
    }
```

also your code is invalid as it assumes to be run in order to display new q-o-d, if you would modify it so whenever application starts it loads and parses the XML (holding reference to laoded XML or creating Vector of questions then on each activation you could check what is the day and update the textfield. It is better to have your app opened once and then brought from background than killing it everytime users is going away e.g. to pick up phone. To achieve this you would use activate/deactivate listeners and appriopriately execute puase/resume(update) actions.

[Like here](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/resuming-using-eventactivate)

best regards